# Repeating rows in numpy according to a vector of indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a matrix B:

```
B = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7]
]
```

and a vector a:

```
a = [0,0,1,1,2]
```

I need to define a new vector C such that it repeats the rows in B as specified by a, i.e.,

```
C = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [0, 1, 2],
    [2, 3, 4]
    [2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7]
]
```

Is there a trick command to do this in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `a` as an [index array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays) here.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> b = np.array([
    [0, 1, 2],
    [2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7]
])
>>> a = [0,0,1,1,2]
>>> b[a]
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7]])
```

And from the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays):

> For all cases of index arrays, what is returned is a **copy** of the
>   original data, not a view as one gets for slices.

In pure Python you can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> B = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7]
]
>>> [B[x][:] for x in a]
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Note that `[:]` returns a shallow copy of the lists, if the lists contains mutable objects then you'll have to use `copy.deepcopy` to get a completely new copy.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ashwini! It is so intuitive :)

Comment: I would recommend `B.take(a, axis=0)` over this. It has been shown many times that take is superior in performance to fancy indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map()` to iterate though all elements of `a` and get the corresponding lists from `B`:

```
C = map(lambda x: B[x], a)
```

Please note that the elements of `C` will only be references to the rows of `B`. This might be the behaviour you want. If you need a real copy of the elements, you could return `B[x][:]` in the lambda for one more level of copying, or use `copy.deepcopy()` for a complete copy.

Comment: Note that the inner lists are still going to be the same objects here.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary You're right, thanks. That's probably useful information. I've edited my answer.